# Tell me more about that

Tags: riddle, word

> The prefix of my prefix is not real
>
> My prefix was not declared real
>
> My infix is basically natural
>
> My suffix is everything else
>
> And if you owe me, I'll come pounding at your door

**What am I?**

Comment: Wow another take on a Riley Riddle :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the old Fortran joke:

> GOD is Real, unless declared Integer (variable types in Fortran)

I'd say

> "Int" is the prefix, and "i" the prefix of the prefix. The base(-ically) natural is "e", and everything else is the "rest"

Making the answer:

> Interest, which if owed, could lead to debt collectors at your door

This also fits nicely with the title, as:

> "Tell me more about that" is displaying Interest

Comment: Yep, this is correct! I don't know if it is proper for me to accept immediately or wait a day like on other SE sites. In any case I will be accepting this answer as it is the first to be correct.